# Ghostscript.NET.Rasterizer set resolution (Dpi) is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ghostscript.net

I have this code to convert pdf to tif, it is faster then ImageMagick library so I have to use it. Every
 thing work good but when I set the **x and y dpi** it always get ignored. I tried different versions of NuGet GhostScript and I also tried different versions of ghostscript.exe still same issue

Here is my code:

```
        var xDpi = 300; //set the x DPI
        var yDpi = 300; //set the y DPI

        using (var rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer()) //create an instance for GhostscriptRasterizer
        {

            rasterizer.Open(fileName); //opens the PDF file for rasterizing
            int PdfPages = rasterizer.PageCount;
            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
            {
                //set the output image(png's) complete path
                string outputPNGPath = Path.Combine(fileNameResultDirectory, "00" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".tif");


                //converts the PDF pages to png's 
                Image pdf2PNG = rasterizer.GetPage(xDpi, yDpi, pageNumber);//it gets ignored here.

                //save the png's
                pdf2PNG.Save(outputPNGPath, ImageFormat.Tiff);
            }



        }
```

Also tried:

```
 rasterizer.CustomSwitches.Add("-r300x300");
```

Also tried:

```
      private static void Test()
        {
            var localGhostscriptDll = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "gsdll64.dll");
            var localDllInfo = new GhostscriptVersionInfo(localGhostscriptDll);

            int desired_x_dpi = 160;
            int desired_y_dpi = 160;

            string inputPdfPath = @"d:\d.pdf";

            string outputPath = @"d:\Test\test.jpg";

            GhostscriptRasterizer _rasterizer = new GhostscriptRasterizer();

            _rasterizer.Open(inputPdfPath, localDllInfo, false);

            for (int pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= _rasterizer.PageCount; pageNumber++)
            {
                string pageFilePath = Path.Combine(outputPath, "Page-" + pageNumber.ToString() + ".png");

                Image img = _rasterizer.GetPage(desired_x_dpi, desired_y_dpi, pageNumber);
                img.Save(pageFilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
            }

            _rasterizer.Close();
        }
```

In this case I added gsdll32.dll manually to this environment path ..\bin\debug
But I get this error:
**Ghostscript.NET.GhostscriptException: 'Delegate of an exported function couldn't be created for symbol 'gsapi_revision''**

Any idea why the x and y dpi gets ignored and in the properties it is gets set to either 96 or 120 as vertical/horizontal resolution. 
I appreciate any help.